# Google Places v3 API autocomplete - cannot get locality working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I had been using the following code, which was working fine for a week or so, i've come back to work on it further and it no longer seems to work. I am wanting to show localities only. Looking at Google's documentation "locality" is the correct option to do so. I was thinking that perhaps google changed the API or something. As soon as i switch it to geocode it works but shows all streets and places, which is not what I want. I also tried ["locality","political"] as well with no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

    var Newoptions = {
      types: ["locality"]
    }; 

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,Newoptions);

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<input id="searchTextField" name="member_location" value="" type="text" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Locality is not always provided in the results, so you have to provide a fallback if you're in an area with no locality, like administrative_area_level_3, though the only one you will always get is country, so you'd better have it fallback eventually to there.

Comment: but why is it so? is it because the Google Maps API don't know/ define the localties for that geographical area yet e.g. country like Singapore?

Answer (score 0):

In your code , you have used

```
 var Newoptions = {
      types: ["locality"] //This is not proper types. 
    };
```

Use **types: ['(regions)']**
Instead. Then retrieve locality Form that. Sample Code is bellow and it works fine.

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     (document.getElementById('YOURsearchBOXID')),
       { types: ['(regions)']});

       google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

         for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == "locality")
            {
                console.log(place['address_components'][i]['long_name']);
            break;
            }
         }

    });
```